# visual studio 2017 windows 10 emulator not found

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

I'm studying UWP on VS2017, I have installed win 10 mobile emulator.
 [image: installer] , but I still can't find it in the dropdown list
[image: dropdownlist].

How to solve it?

Comment: No need to emulate Win10 when you run on Win10, so just select "Local machine".

Comment: @HansPassant actually I want to run it on win10 mobile.

Comment: Does your PC meet the [system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the latest OS build version of Windows 10 mobile is 15254, there is no 16299 or higher version mobile system. So, if your project's target version is 16299 or higher, there're no emulators.

If you switch your project's target version to 15063, then you will see the emulators.